# Micronaut: How can I use serialization inclucion ALWAYS with Micronaut Serialization?

Tags: serialization, micronaut, micronaut-serde

How is it possible to configure the Micronaut Serde objectMapper to include all properties when serializing, and not just the non-null values?

For Jackson the similar code looks like this:

```
new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper()
.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
```

Sample:

```
    @Test
    void testObjectMapper() throws IOException {
        var name = new Name("My first", null);
        var expected = """
                {"first":"My first", "last": null}
                """;
        var json = ObjectMapper.getDefault().writeValueAsString(name);
        assertEquals(expected, json);
    }

    @Introspected
    @Serdeable
    public record Name(String first, String last) {
    }
```

I want the json to be

```
{"first":"My first", "last": null}
```

and not just

```
{"first":"My first"}
```

Comment: You can combine the jackson annotation.

just ensure you also have io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-processor (this handles the mapping of jackson annotation)

@Serdeable
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
public record Name(String first, String last) {    }